# JavaFX Scene Builder Button Bar Spacing

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to work on a JavaFX project and I'm using the Gluon SceneBuilder to help my build my scenes, so it doesn't take so long. I am removing the default window border and attempting to include my own function buttons (close window, minimize, maximize) and I'm using a ButtonBar at the top of the window to add these in, but for some reason, the buttons aren't working with their spacing like I want them to.

I plan on putting them all directly next to each other with no space in between, but I can't get this to work correctly. I've looked through all the different settings and options for the buttons as well as the button bar and nowhere in there does it say that there's a margin or padding in any of them, but they're still getting spaced out as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVJji.jpg). How can I make it so that they don't have a spacing in between?

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: Why you did not use `Toolbar` and customise by using `-fx-spacing` property in css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reasons to save your Button Bar and you don't want to use other layouts directly (Toolbar or HBox) ,you can add a Hbox to your Button Bar and add your buttons into your hbox like this :

```
<ButtonBar buttonOrder="L_HE+U+FBIX_NCYOA_T" layoutX="130.0" layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="0.0" stylesheets="@fx.css" ButtonBar.buttonData="APPLY">
    <buttons>
        <HBox>
           <children>
              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
    </buttons>
  </ButtonBar>
```

And the result is [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use HBox instead of ButtonBar. Something like this:

```
 <HBox prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
        <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <Button text="Button" />
        <Button text="Button" />
        <Button text="Button" />
     </children>
  </HBox>
```

Comment: But a ButtonBar is essentially a HBox, with the additional functionality for operating system specific button placement.

Comment: What do you don't need is "specific button placement". Just try to implement your buttons (labels, images) in this way. Pane (in this example) is just a "spacer" between some elements. In this case it simply cause that your buttons appear always top-right

Answer (score 2):

The ButtonBar presets a certain layout, which is not supposed to be customized very much. Try one or many ToolBar(s) combined with other layout panes like GridPane, FlowPane or HBox instead. For example this one creates 3 Buttons always on the upper right corner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <top>
      <GridPane>
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="10.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <ToolBar prefHeight="30.0" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.valignment="TOP" />
            <ToolBar prefHeight="30.0" style="-fx-padding: 0;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
               <items>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-margin: 0;" text="Button" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" style="margin: 0;" text="Button" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </items>
            </ToolBar>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```